# Print Value from JSON URL with php twitter

Tags: php, json, url, twitter

Im trying to print values from a json file to my website.
I realise there is a API system for twitter how ever for the intended purpose i dont feel its needed to apply for a twitter api and wait just for a follower count status.

im not sure why. but nothing is displayed.
Is there something im missing?

Here is my current code

```js
$json = file_get_contents('https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com/widgets/followbutton/info.json?screen_names=stackoverflow');

$data = json_decode($json,true);

$twitcount = $data['followers_count'][0];

echo "<b>";
print_r($twitcount);
```

Visting the url below will push a json file with basic infomation about the twitter account.
https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com/widgets/followbutton/info.json?screen_names=stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

If you run `var_export($data);` you'll get:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'following' => false,
    'id' => '128700677',
    'screen_name' => 'StackOverflow',
    'name' => 'Stack Overflow',
    'protected' => false,
    'followers_count' => 55359,
    'formatted_followers_count' => '55.4K followers',
    'age_gated' => false,
  ),
)
```

So your code needs to be `$twitcount = $data[0]['followers_count'];`

Comment: hmm, makes sence, but im still having issues.
Not sure what exactly is causing this. problem for me

I either get NULL

or nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

correct your index

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [following] => 
            [id] => 128700677
            [screen_name] => StackOverflow
            [name] => Stack Overflow
            [protected] => 
            [followers_count] => 55358
            [formatted_followers_count] => 55.4K followers
            [age_gated] => 
        )

)

$twitcount = $data[0]['followers_count'];

Comment: Still getting NULL

Even if i do

var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

Comment: $json = file_get_contents('https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com/widgets/followbutton/info.json?screen_names=stackoverflow'); 
$data = json_decode($json,true);
$twitcount = $data[0]['followers_count'];
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
print_r($twitcount);

Comment: try to use this code this will help cheers.. and make sure your json variable has data try to echo $json before decode it.

Comment: Thank you all the answers worked acctually.
Just had some conflicts with file_get_contents

Ended up going with a CURL solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

```html
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com/widgets/followbutton/info.json?screen_names=stackoverflow');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


$data = json_decode($result,true);
$twitcount = $data[0]['followers_count'];
print_r($twitcount);
```

All your answers where correct and great thank you

I ended up setting it up with CURL instead.
Seems like iv got some issues with file_get_contents

Maybe some sort of conflict.